# Session fixation with session in cookies

Tags: security, session, web-applications

There are a lot of questions and answers about session fixation on StackOverflow, however, I am still confused about one thing. People often suggest that storing session in cookies is not enough to overcome the session fixation issue and you should rotate the session id after login. I can imagine that if you only use the session id to identify a user, you may still be vulnerable to an attack. However, I would like to ask about one specific case.

Let's assume that you use a signed cookie to store the whole session. On login you put into the cookie an id identifying the user. After logout, you delete the id. You do not change the session id, but as you change the session itself and you sign it, I cannot see any attack scenario taking advantage of this design. Is session fixation still an issue and, hence, is session id rotation still necessary in this case? If yes, can you provide an attack that could be used? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basics of Session Fixation is that it’s possible for an attacker to make the victim use a session that the attacker has access to. This is generally done by inducing the victim to use a certain session ID that is known to the attacker and doesn’t change after authentication.

Now what you’ve described doesn’t sound like a session identifier but rather a simple client-side data storage of user authentication data.

But nonetheless, if you make the cookie data dependent on data that again depends on the authenticated user which additionally is signed by the server, it certainly will change after authentication and won’t be known to the attacker. Then the security of that scheme depends on its actual implementation.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so, just wanted to check I didn't forget about some obscure case when an attacker could fixate a session.